# How can I hold the selected element's node by value (and not reference) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I had to remove everything in the `body` except for images in the DOM.
So, this is what I did.

1. Stored the img tags in the variable.

   `var img_nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('img');`
2. Removed every thing inside the `body`

   `var body_node = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
   body_node[0].innerHTML = ''`
3. Added the stored img nodes as children

   `for each (child in img_nodes){
           body.appendChild(child);
    }`

But after I had run `body_node[0].innerHTML = ''`, the img_nodes became `undefined`.

I guess that happened because element node was being stored in list as objects (as a reference). How can I save my selected img_nodes objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could clone the image nodes before clearing the body contents. See [the documentation on cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). Example:

```
var cloned_nodes = [];
for each (child in img_nodes){
    cloned_nodes.push(child.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: very idiomatic - great answer